# routes and component not refreshing

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a super small website with 3 pages, `home`, `about us` and `services`, so the urls are `http://localhost:4200`/ , `http://localhost:4200/about-us` and `http://localhost:4200/services`

I have a `PagesComponent` with which i want to console log `url slugs`, so an empty string for the root (or undefined as I am getting now which is fine), and for the other 2 when I click their respective links in the navbar I expect to console log `about-us` and `services`.

These are my routes:

```
{ path: ':page', component: PagesComponent },
{ path: '', component: PagesComponent },
```

And my `PagesComponent`

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            this.param = params['page']; 
         });
        console.log(this.param);
    }
```

The problem is, if I click let's say `services` link first, I get `services` in the console (which is correct), BUT if I **then** click `about-us`, I get nothing. And vice versa.

Also if I click `home` link I get `undefined` (which is fine), and then if I click either `about-us` or `services` I get that slug logged, but not if I click them both one after another (in any order).

It's acting as if `{ path: ':page', component: PagesComponent },` route cannot be refreshed before another route is reached.

Also, if I click a link (any link I have) and I get something in the console, if I keep clicking the same link I do not get anything again, I guess it is the same underlying issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried moving the console.log inside the subscribe? That way it will log every time an item is emitted, and not just on initialization?

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.param = params['page']; 
        console.log(this.param);
     });
}
```

I tried something similar with an app I have,

```
this.route.params
  .subscribe(
    (params: Params) => {
      this.id = params['id'];
      this.preptestDetails  = this.ptService.getPreptest(this.id);
      console.log('inside subscribe: ' + this.id);
    }
  );
console.log('outside subscribe: ' + this.id);
```

Here's the console log. Note how the log outside of subscribe only fires once and the one inside fires every time.

> inside subscribe: 9
>
> outside subscribe: 10
>
> inside subscribe: 11
>
> inside subscribe: 23
>
> inside subscribe: 3
>
> inside subscribe: 5
>
> inside subscribe: 6
>
> inside subscribe: 7
>
> inside subscribe: 4

Comment: This does help, it now recognizes a link is clicked always, but it still does not respond if I click the same link multiple times, any idea why?

Comment: I'm assuming that is because if you click on the same link twice, the route doesn't change the second time, so the observable you're subscribed to doesn't emit.

Comment: @VojislavKovacevic -- you could handle it with a click listener on the link (click)="onClickLogPageParams()" & instead logging to the console when you subscribe, you could do onClickLogPageParams() { console.log(this.param) }